# C# Get values from a Json string

Tags: c#, json.net

I am getting a Json string from an API using REST and I'm trying to display the values from the Json string in the Console but I have been unable to do so. Every time I look at a working example online, it does not seem to work for me.

This is the Json string the API returns:

```
{"error":false,"players":[{"name":"Beyluta","steamId":"76561198078571545","discordId":"407309344456179713","insertDate":"2018-11-18 12:31:31","language":"br"}]}
```

And this is the code I am using:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public string discordId { set; get; }
    public string steamId { set; get; }
}

private void getPendingPlayersTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create($"http://localhost/bf/api/GetPendingPlayers.php");

        request.Timeout = 1000;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", apiClass.ApiKey);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var rawJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            var details = JObject.Parse(rawJson);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("SteamID: ", details["steamId"]));
        }
    }
```

And the console returns:
[Screenshot of what the console returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkUxW.png)

I never worked with this before so I have no other leads, pretty much all other solutions I found online resulted in the same issue.

The program simply needs to display the three variables in the UserInfo class.

One thing I noticed:

```
string jsonData = @"{  
        'steamId':'000000000000',  
        'discordId':'1111111111'  
        }";
```

Using the format above I was able to read the values just fine, however I have to use the string that the API passes to me.

What could be problem be?

Comment: `Players` is an array of objects which each have properties name, discordid, etc. You would need to try `details["players"][0]["steamId"]` I believe..where players would get you the array and then index it to zero to get the first object then key of steamid

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and take a look at `details`? That is a good way to see what is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan Wilson's Answer is correct, the code below worked just fine!

```
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var rawJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        var details = JObject.Parse(rawJson);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("SteamID: ", ["players"][0]["steamId"]));
    }
}
```